# Separated in ListView.separated doesn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

what I try to do. I try to make separated in ListView.separated to data I get it from database but that not work I don't know why. I have a table this table have many column in database like Name and Age and location ..etc.

Now I want to show one row from this table to the user in ListView.separated so I want to make between this data separated like between( Name separated  Age separated  Location separated  ..etc)like that.

I know if I'm bringing multiple set of row data from the database, there's going to be a split between each row, but now I'm trying to show one row  then bring all data  of column of this row and then  be a split between each column data.

I need to make it automatic not by add one by one divider() after each line.

Table:

```
+---------+--------------+---------------------+
| user_id | Name         | Age       | Lcation |
+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|    1    | Irene        | 22        |   A     |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Code:

```
 Container(
      child:

      FutureBuilder(
    future: ApiService().TopOne(ID),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Divider(
              thickness: 1,
            );
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Name']}"),
                Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Age']}"),
                Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Location']}"),
                Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Others']}"),
              ],
            ));
          },
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
            child: Image.asset(
          'assets/nodata.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 180,
          height: 180,
        ));
      }

 
      return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/no_dataa.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 180,
          height: 180,
        ),
      ));
    },
  ));
}
```

Image as what I try to do:
[image]

Any one knows what the error in my code how can I solve this problem?
thank you.

Comment: Can you include an image of your desire output?

Comment: Hello brother, I added more details what I need, the question has been updated @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Hi bro / I add same image as what I try to do @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `Divider` inside `Column` widget.

```dart
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Name']}"),
      Divider(),
       Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Age']}"),
      Divider(),
      Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Location']}"),
      Divider(),
       Text("${snapshot.data[index]['Others']}"),
      Divider(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

If you dont want to have divider end of the Column, you can use just `.builder`

Comment: yes bro but I need to make it automatic not like that

Comment: It will get on every Item on Build,  Can you test it out and share what went wrong

Comment: Hello brother, yes, in the end I did it. There is no different way. Even if it exists, it is a little complicated and takes a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was working on a different point